# ARCore for Unity save camera image

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, arcore

Using ARCore for Unity, trying to save     `Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes()` as image and scanning the image for QR code. But the converted image is not in actual scale and it is repeating, so not able to deduct the QR code correctly.

Here is my code

```
void Update()
{
using (var image = Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes())
    {
        if (image.IsAvailable)
        {               

            byte[] m_EdgeImage = null;
            Color32[] pixels = null;
            IParser Parser = new ZXingParser();
            if (_texture == null || m_EdgeImage == null || _texture.width != image.Width || _texture.height != image.Height)
            {
                _texture = new Texture2D(image.Width, image.Height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false, false);                    
                m_EdgeImage = new byte[image.Width * image.Height*4];           

            }
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(image.Y, m_EdgeImage, 0, image.Width * image.Height);               
            _texture.LoadRawTextureData(m_EdgeImage);
            _texture.Apply();       

            ParserResult Result = Parser.Decode(pixels, _texture.width, _texture.height);
            if (Result != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("QRCODE");

            }
            else
            {               
                var encodedJpg = _texture.EncodeToJPG();
                var path = Application.persistentDataPath;
                File.WriteAllBytes(path + "/test.jpg", encodedJpg);             
                Debug.Log("NOQRCODE");
                Application.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the converted image

[image]

What is wrong here

Answer (score 1):

An ARCore camera image with its data accessible from the CPU in YUV-420-888 format[Check this](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/unity/struct/GoogleARCore/CameraImageBytes). The buffer size is width*height*1.5 for YUV. You may need to convert YUV to RGB format.