# How to get ARCore AcquireCameraImageBytes() in color?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, computer-vision, arcore

I've been stuck on this problem for days. I am trying to do some image processing on my project. I have looked over the computer vision example `ARCore` provides but it only shows how to access the camera frame in black and white. I need color for my images. I've already looked at [Save AcquireCameraImageBytes() from Unity ARCore to storage as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579334/save-acquirecameraimagebytes-from-unity-arcore-to-storage-as-an-image)
and had no luck.

I have a function called `GetImage()` that is supposed to return the camera frame as a texture.

```
public Texture GetImage() {

    if (!Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes().IsAvailable) {
        return null;
    }

    var ptr = Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes();
    var bufferSize = ptr.Width * ptr.Height * 4;

    if (_tex == null) {
        _tex = new Texture2D(ptr.Width, ptr.Height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false, false);
    }

    if (_bytes == null) {
        _bytes = new byte[bufferSize];
    }

    Marshal.Copy(_ptr.Y, _bytes, 0, bufferSize);
    _tex.LoadRawTextureData(_bytes);
    _tex.Apply();
    return _tex;
}
```

I run into two problems with this code.

First, after a few seconds my app freezes with the error "failed to acquire camera image with status error resources exhausted".

The second issue is if I do manage to display the image it is not in color and is repeated four times like in this post [ARCore for Unity save camera image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798067/arcore-for-unity-save-camera-image).

Does anyone have a working example of accessing ARCore images in color or know what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

With "Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes();" you get a greyscale image in the YUV-420-888 format [(see doc)](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/unity/struct/GoogleARCore/CameraImageBytes) So with the right YUV to RGB transformation you should get a color camera image. (But I didn't find a right YUV to RGB transformation, yet)
I had a similiar questsion: [ARCore Save Camera Image (Unity C#) on Button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49924802/arcore-save-camera-image-unity-c-on-button-click?noredirect=1&lq=1) in my updated question I posted code which get me the greyscale image from AcquireCameraImagesBytes().

If you want to do image processing, did you already looked at the [Unity Computer Vision Example.](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/tree/master/Assets/GoogleARCore/Examples/ComputerVision) example? See the [_OnImageAvailable](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/blob/master/Assets/GoogleARCore/Examples/ComputerVision/Scripts/ComputerVisionController.cs#L150) With the TextureReader API you can get colored images.
Also this github issue could be helpful: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/221